# Motherboard rejects identical hard drive, one works the other doesn't

Tags: dell, sata, hardware, supermicro

I have an interesting situation. I have a Dell XS23-SB server that has four blades in it. The blades use Supermicro X7DWT motherboards, and interface with the sata drives through a backplane.

I took two identical drives from a raid 0 enclosure that came from the factory (GDrive), one works on all four servers, the other does not. I verified that they both work by plugging them into a hard drive cradle.

This behavior can be repeated with other drives, some drives work and some don't. However when i test them, they ALL work on my PC.

What could cause this?

Comment: All you're doing is plugging them in? What do you mean "it doesn't work" it gets an error message? The RAID controller or BIOS doesn't recognize them? What troubleshooting have you completed.

Comment: @SpacemanSpiff When I get to the windows installation it can't find the drives. As I mentioned one half of a raid 0 works, e.g. one of the two drives works. I figured this out last night I'll post the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After considering the situation, I realized that all of the drives that were having issues were part of raid configurations that I had dismantled. The specific issue was that Windows installation could not find some of the drives from these raid configurations. The raid levels I had used for multiple arrays were 5 and 0 respectively.

I theorized that even though I had tested and formatted these drives with NTFS, that there was left over raid information hidden on them that was causing a conflict with Windows or the X7DWT sata controller.

In order to resolve this issue I zeroed the drives and they then worked without any issues.